# JavaFX still truncates the Alert messages

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I am trying to show an Alert with a long message, and it tends to get truncated at a word boundary.

I think it's only a Windows and Linux issue. I found some answers that propose this solution: `alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);`.

Or this one:

`alert.getDialogPane().getChildren().stream().filter(node -> node instanceof Label).forEach(node -> ((Label)node).setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE));`

However, I still have the same problem on my CentOS.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, Messages.AoiPanel_confirmation_message, ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
alert.setTitle("");
alert.initOwner(deleteButton.getScene().getWindow());
alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.showAndWait();
```

This is what I mean by get truncated at a word boundary (sorry I can't share the image of the real application as my centOS is a secure OS and the application is private).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, I use win7 + java 1.8.0_102 and xubuntu + java 1.8.0_111 and the text is only truncated after 12 lines. But because the alert dialog doesn't seem to extend horizontally by default and most of the messages in my project are rather long, I also use...

```
alert.getDialogPane().setMinWidth(600);
```

... so I don't have that problem any more.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the alert dialog does not extend vertically or horizontally using `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`, and neither vertically using `setMinHeight(600)` so I will use your solution.

Comment: I'm glad it helped at least a bit. But I recommend NOT to remove that `alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)` line. As mentioned above, with the newer java version it seems to extend vertically and display up to 12 lines.